# Battery Not Present XPS 15z U13.10

Tags: 12.04, indicator, power-management, battery, 13.10

So I recently reopened my old laptop which was running ubuntu 12.04 lts.

When I opened it, i noticed the battery was stated has ''Not Present'' in the top menu bar.

When I click on that label, it gets me to the power statistic menu where i can choose between Latop battery and AC adapter.

If i click on the battery tab. it tells me those confusing informations:

Everything there is to id. my battery (serial, producer, model,max wh, voltage..)
But it also says Charging but the charge does not go up. It also says rechargable Yes and present yes.

So i have got an OS that says the battery is not present, but it's charging because it's present but it's not charging because it's not there... Quite surprising lol.

So before taking out the battery or replacing the AC  ( I do know both function properly...)

I went in the BIOS. Since it's a dell laptop there is an indicator of the health of my battery and if the ac adapter is working properly...

Guess what, the battery is healthy and the ac adapter is too.

So i upgraded to 12.10, 13.04 and 13.10 hoping there would be a fix...

There was none, and what is even more strange, is that the battery actually did work before i let my laptop in a locker for 5 months...

Can someone help me out, i would really like to get the use of the battery again....

Comment: I still need help on this one.... Can someone explain me how to deal with this...

Comment: Please help me out.